# Sign in (retrieve IdToken) in background (without user interaction)

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

Is there a way to signIn (obtain idToken) in background:

- with username and password (assuming that the background task will provide username and password),
- with one IdProviders (assuming that the background task will provide the email/id and the id of the provider).

By implementing UiManager without actual UI I managed utilize GitkitClient so that the user does not have to interact with the UI (for both username/password and Google provider), but it still has to be executed inside of an activity.

What I am trying to achieve is a scenario where the user is logging in once and the token is refreshed when it expires after 2 weeks in background without user interaction.

Comment: You should add which flavor of GIT you are using, Andoid, iOS, Web. The documentation states that re-engaging the user may cause for a captcha or SMS-confirmation, meaning GIT can't be used in purely background applications; especially if you have the password (as this may be bruteforced).

Comment: I use Android client. I understand that if there is requirement for user interaction application should notify user, but I think it is inconvenient if an  app is asking user every 2 weeks to login or just click the gmail account that he/she uses. So it would be nice if there was a way to refresh the token without user interaction (and if it will provoke requirement for user interaction, let the developer deal with it).